# htaccess rule to forward /login/ and /login to same page?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following rule in my current .htaccess file to redirect `/videos/login/` requests to `/videos/login.php`

```
RewriteRule login/ /videos/login.php
```

This works fine if I am access login page using `http://mysite.com/videos/login/` but when I am trying to access the same page using `http://mysite.com/videos/login` (without ending slash) then it gives me "404 page not found" error.

Please tell me what will be the correct rule of .htaccess file so that any request for `http://mysite.com/videos/login/` or `http://mysite.com/videos/login` will point to the same /videos/login.php page.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just make the trailing slash optional:

```
RewriteRule ^videos/login/?$ /videos/login.php
```

But you should better use just one variant (with or without trailing slash) and redirect one to the other:

```
# add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @Gumbo your Rule is working fine, its opening the same page with and without slash, but I want when any one will access the /videos/login then he will be redirected to /videos/login/ is it possible using htaccess.

Comment: I just mentioned both options. If you want the trailing slash, just use the former.

Comment: But #add trailing slash will add slashes to all my URLs, which I don't want, there are some selected URLs for which I want this facility

Comment: A trailing slash will be added to every URL path that cannot be mapped to an existing file (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`). But if you don’t want that, list those URL paths you want it for with a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(videos/login|foo/bar|baz/quux|…)$` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This work fine for me:

Rewriterule ^login(/|)$    /videos/login.php

Answer (score 1):

Using mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/videos/login/?$
RewriteRule (.*) /videos/login.php [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect 301 /videos/login/index.html http://yoursite.com/videos/login.php

The server will change the address http://mysite.com/videos/login/ and http://mysite.com/videos/login both to http://mysite.com/videos/login/index.html, based on the configuration but this is default. Before it encounters a 404 this address is redirected to the new one. At least this works at my site.
```

Had to use pre because the site let's me post only one hyperlink :/