# .htaccess RewriteRule not being followed

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess

I'm getting a "Page not found" when I try to use the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /free-demo [NC]
RewriteRule partner/(.*)/free-demo/(.*) /free-demo/$2 [L]
```

What I am trying to do is have traffic that accesses `test.com/partner/DYNAMIC-CONTENT/free-demo/DYNAMIC-CONTENT/` load the content located at `test.com/free-demo/DYNAMIC-CONTENT/`

If I attempt to access `test.com/free-demo/DYNAMIC-CONTENT/` directly, I am able to access the content. If I attempt to access `test.com/partner/DYNAMIC-CONTENT/free-demo/DYNAMIC-CONTENT/` I get a "Page not found" message.

RewriteEngine is on and if I modify the .htaccess file with invalid code I get a server 500 error so I know that the .htaccess is processing. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do your web server logs say?

Comment: @Crontab I'm developing locally using MAMP. My httpd.conf file says my apache_error.log is located at /Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log and is not returning any errors. LogLevel is set to "error".

Comment: What about your access logs?  They should at least tell you the page that the server is attempting to retrieve after applying your rewrite rules.  From there, you should be able to figure out where the setup went wrong.

Comment: Just checking you do have "RewriteEngine On" before your rules. Otherwise your rewrite just worked fine for me

Comment: @afxdesign I do have RewriteEngine On

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your post I am assuming the following:

The url that is being accessed on the web is: 
test.com/partner/DYNAMIC-CONTENT/free-demo/DYNAMIC-CONTENT/

And the url you want to rewrite to is: 
test.com/free-demo/DYNAMIC-CONTENT/

I notice that you have 2 sets of DYNAMIC-CONTENT in the addressable URL and only one set internal. Seeing the $2 in your example I'll assume you are ignoring the first and using the second for the internal url.

** a more specific example would be nice here.

Try this:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /partner/(.*)/free-demo/(.*) [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) /free-demo/%2 [L]
```

Comment: You are correct in your assumptions above. When trying your code, it works fine EXCEPT if my accessing URL does not end with a trailing slash. For example, `test.com/partner/DYNAMIC-CONTENT/free-demo/DYNAMIC-CONTENT` redirects the user to `test.com/free-demo/DYNAMIC-CONTENT/` rather than just loading in the content. If I do `test.com/partner/DYNAMIC-CONTENT/free-demo/DYNAMIC-CONTENT/` it works as expected. My access_logs follow:

"GET /partner/test/free-demo/dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12
"GET /partner/test/free-demo/dashboard HTTP/1.1" 301 257

Comment: There are many questions dealing with the trailing slash rules. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106235/htaccess-rule-to-forward-login-and-login-to-same-page

Comment: Thanks, I have been looking at the trailing slash rules. It appears that I cannot get both the trailing slash and your sample code above to fire, it is one or the other. Any thoughts on that? This is what I am using for the trailing slash rewrite: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,QSA,NC]

Comment: Just have 2 explicit rules, one with and one without. It's not elegant, but will work.

Comment: Adding trailing slash to the one rule seems to work for me e.g. RewriteRule ^(.*) /free-demo/%2/ [L]

Comment: tanstaafi Am curious why you just edited your answer to add back slashes (.\\*). The condition doesn't work now?

Comment: Sorry, they were misplaced. I didn't see the markup for code snippets. It's my mistake.

Comment: Using @tanstaafl comment above works, I also use the following to handle the forced trailing slash and it works just fine: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC] RewriteRule .*[^/]$ /$0/ [R,L] --- thanks to all who have contributed :)